# Error `this set of changes has already been published`

Tags: php

A few days ago, having made some CSS changes in my `additional css` box, I got this error.

`Looks like something's gone wrong. Wait a few seconds and try again.`

I waited a few seconds and pressed `publish` again. This time I got another error message:

`The previous set of changes has already been published. Please try saving your current set of changes again`.

I tried again and got the first error message again.

Not sure what's caused this because the changes haven't been published before but, just to make sure, I deleted all my recent css changes and tried to save, at which point the error messages started displaying again.

I've had a look and it seems that the previous version of WordPress had a bug which was apparently fixed. So I reinstalled my current WordPress version (the latest).

The issue still persisted.

So I looked up php location of my `additional css` input box amd managed to find `wp_posts` in `information_schema` in `phpMyAdmin`

Now, having looked at several entries there, I can find nothing to indicate what's causing the issue.

So I'm looking for a fix for what seems to be a bug.

Site: [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: I believe this might be a theme related issue, have you tried contacting your theme developer?

Comment: That's an excellent idea, I will. What makes you think it's a theme rather than WordPress issue, if you don't mind my asking? Thanks.

Comment: It’s not a core bug from what I can see and additional css is customizer option directly related to your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll ask and possibly get back if i can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try in private window. If you backed out too quick browser might be telling CMS this was already done. Try clearing the WP cache too